# Deleted migration files- how to makemigrations without losing data

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I changed a field on a model class (which has no classes point *to* it, only one foreign key pointing out of it). Somehow, this stuffed up my migrations and it keeps saying "django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError:" looking for migration files that do not exist.

I accidentally deleted several files in my 'migrations' folder.

My database contains a lot of data, and I do not want to break it.

Will I lose any data if I:

1. Remove the table that caused the problem in the first place (psql, \d, DROP TABLE tablename)
2. **delete all my migration files**
3. Re run the migration from the start?

   ./manage.py makemigrations

   ./manage.py migrate

Can anyone recommend another way of fixing this?

Here is the traceback:
http://dpaste.com/0Y1YDXS

Comment: "deleted several files in my 'migrations' folder." - Can you not just restore them from your source control? Also, include the traceback in here, links die

Comment: I _am_ using git but it looks like it was set under .gitignore!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aren't you using git so that you can get your migration files back? If not, **install and use it, starting now**

I would suggest:

1. **make a backup/dump of your database first**, in case something goes wrong
2. Delete all migrations
3. Empty migration table in psql
4. call `makemigrations`
5. call `migrate --fake-initial`

Comment: Will that break my users or anything?

Comment: Also, when you say empty-  do you mean just delete the table (drop table)?

Answer (score 5):

1. Empty the django_migrations table:

   ```
   delete from django_migrations;
   ```
2. Remove all the files in migrations folders in each and every app of your project.
3. Reset the migrations for the "built-in" apps:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate --fake
   ```
4. Create initial migrations for each and every app:

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
   ```
5. Final step is to create fake initial migrations:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
   ```

See here https://micropyramid.com/blog/how-to-create-initial-django-migrations-for-existing-schema/